# Redshift - Updating a specific column in Redshift DB

Tags: sql-update, amazon-redshift, increment

I have a sales table that stores the sale data. This table gets updated once every day (incremental update). I am trying to update one of the columns in this table to calculate the aging since the sale_date.

```
update sales set aging = (select CASE WHEN sale_date > current_date-28 AND sale_date < current_date -14 THEN '2 - 4 Weeks Ago'
                    WHEN terminated_at > current_date-14 AND terminated_at < current_date THEN '0 - 2 Weeks Ago'
                    WHEN terminated_at < current_date-28 THEN '4+ Weeks Ago' ELSE 'Unknown' end as aging from sales) ;
```

I get Invalid operation : invalid query error. Could anyone help me find where am I going wrong with this.

I am using a Amazon Redshift DB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can just remove the `select` on the RHS side of your update:

```
UPDATE sales
SET aging = CASE WHEN sale_date > current_date - 28 AND sale_date < current_date - 14
                 THEN '2 - 4 Weeks Ago'
                 WHEN terminated_at > current_date - 14 AND terminated_at < current_date
                 THEN '0 - 2 Weeks Ago'
                 WHEN terminated_at < current_date - 28
                 THEN '4+ Weeks Ago'
                 ELSE 'Unknown' END;
```

But, I feel that perhaps you should not be storing this information in your SQL table.  Rather, you can generate this output when you select using the same `CASE` expression whenever you need it.  The reason I say this is because as you add new records, and therefore new date information, this computed column would have to be calculated again, and this can be costly.

Comment: Thanks @tim this helped. The reason I am doing it this way is because the current table updates daily incrementally but the aging values are wrong since they are not updated for sales done in the past. I believe this is properly the best bet given the current update structure.